# blogger title only showing in home page

Tags: xml, blogger, blogs, title, blogger-dynamic-views

I have a blogger blog in which I have text as blog title.
In homepage I am able to see the title. But when I open some posts title disappears. I want it to be shown in all pages.

```
    <b:includable id='title'>
        <h1>
          <b:tag cond='data:view.url != data:blog.homepageUrl' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='a'>
            <data:title/>
          </b:tag>
     </h1>

  </b:includable>
```

I tried to give this condition :

```
 <b:tag cond='data:view.url == data:blog.homepageUrl' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='a'>
```

Then it showed the other way. Title appeared in all pages other than homepage.
I want title in all pages.

Comment: Show your blog url!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
          <b:tag expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='a'>
            <data:title/>
          </b:tag>
```

Removing the conditional *cond='data:view.url != data:blog.homepageUrl'* might do the trick.